# Cookie staying around after I delete it and refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies, cookiestore

I'm trying to remove the user's authentication cookie by using `$cookieStore.remove('.ASPXAUTH')`, but if I refresh the page afterwards, the cookie still exists and the page is still available instead of the user being redirected to the login page as I would expect.

Why is the user still able to view the page after I delete the authentication cookie and refresh the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that there isn't much you can do to a http-only cookie with javascript. The backend has to remove it if it's http-only. you can trigger a logout by using ajax.

```
$http.get("/logout");
```

The other option is to use non http cookie so you can modify it with javascript. But that would make it vulnerable and unsafe for risk of an XSS flaw grabbing your cookie and allowing your session to be hijacked.

PS: try HEAD request method if you don't want to load the page that follows (might work like an "do-and-forget-about-it")

```
$http.head("/logout");
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. It was an HttpOnly cookie. I changed it to do an ajax call.